# ReactJS form validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, material-ui

I have simple form validation for react. I made this from this source

http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/02/create-simple-forms-with-validation-in-react-js.html

there is my code. when I submit the form input error occurred inside of the isValid function. please help me to fix this.

AddMember page

```
class AddMember extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading : true,
            formData: {
                fname   : "",
                lname   : "",
                address1: "",
                address2: "",
                city    : "",
                mobile  : "",
                role    : "",
                email   : "",
                gender  : ""
            },
            fields  : []
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.register = this.register.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        document.title = globals.title + "Add New Member";
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({loading: false})
        }, 500);
    }


    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let validForm = true;
        this.state.fields.forEach(function (field) {
            console.log(field.refs[field.props.name]);
            if (typeof field.isValid === "function") {
                let validField = field.isValid(field.refs[field.props.name]);
                validForm = validForm && validField
            }
        });

        if (validForm) {
            console.log(this.state.fields);
        }
    };

    handleChange = (name) => (value) => {
        let formData = {
            [name]: value
        };
        this.setState({
            formData: formData
        })
    };

    register (field)  {
        let s = this.state.fields;
        s.push(field);
        this.setState({fields: s});
        console.log("ss");
    };

    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;

        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <div className={classes.posRelative}>
                    <CircularProgress size={80} className={classes.progress}/>
                </div>
            )
        }

        return (
            <Grow in={true} style={{transformOrigin: "0 0 0"}}>
                <Paper className={classes.root}>
                    <form
                        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                        noValidate>

                        <Grid container spacing={16}>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                                <MuiValidator placeholder={"First Name"} name={"fname"} type={"email"}
                                              onChange={this.handleChange("fname")} value={this.state.formData.fname}
                                              inputProps={{required:true}} onComponentMounted={this.register} fullWidth={true}/>
                            </Grid>

                        </Grid>
                        <Button type={"submit"} variant={"raised"} color={"primary"}>Submit</Button>
                    </form>
                </Paper>
            </Grow>
        );
    }

}
```

validation component

```
class MuiValidator extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error   : "",
            errorMsg: ""
        };
        this.isValid = this.isValid.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange (e) {
        this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
        let isValidField = this.isValid(e.target);
        // console.log(e.target.appendChild());
        console.log(isValidField);

    };

    //Validation function
    isValid (input) {
        console.log(input);
        //check required field
        if (input.getAttribute("required") !== null && input.value === "") {
            this.setState({error: true,errorMsg:'This field is required'});
            return false
        } else {
            this.setState({error: false,errorMsg:''});
            // input.nextSibling.textContent = "";
        }
        if (input.getAttribute("type") === "email" && input.value !== "") {
            if (!this.validateEmail(input.value)) {
                this.setState({error: true, errorMsg: "Please enter valid email address"})
                return false
            } else {
                this.setState({error: false,errorMsg:''});
            }
        }
        return true;
    };

    validateEmail = (value) => {
        let re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(value);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.onComponentMounted) {
            this.props.onComponentMounted(this);
        }
    }


    render() {
        const {error,errorMsg} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <FormControl fullWidth={this.props.fullWidth} margin={"normal"} error={!!error}>
                    <InputLabel>First Name</InputLabel>
                    <Input name={this.props.name} type={this.props.type} placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                           value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange}
                           inputProps={this.props.inputProps} ref={this.props.name}/>
                    {error && <FormHelperText>{errorMsg}</FormHelperText>}
                </FormControl>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

I have no idea how can fix this please help me...

Comment: what's the error in console ?

Comment: TypeError: input.getAttribute is not a function this is the error in  console

Comment: this happens when typing or when submitting, or both ?

Comment: when the form submit. typing is already working no errors

Comment: It’s okay to handle validations manually if we have small form operations. But in case your dealing with large forms use ``formik`` it has great form validation support for react.

Comment: i want to learn working with some function in react.this code for learning

Answer (score 1):

thanks all. finally, I found a solution. I changed the handle submit function like this

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let validForm = true;
        this.state.fields.forEach((field) => {
            //create input element
            let elm = document.createElement("input");
            for (let attr in field.refs[field.props.name].props) {
                if (attr !== "onChange" && attr !== "inputProps") {
                    elm.setAttribute(attr, field.refs[field.props.name].props[attr]);
                    elm.removeAttribute("onChange");
                }
                if (attr === "inputProps") {
                    for (let props in field.refs[field.props.name].props.inputProps) {
                        elm.setAttribute(props, field.refs[field.props.name].props.inputProps[props]);
                    }
                }
            }


            if (typeof field.isValid === "function") {
                let validField = field.isValid(elm);
                validForm = validForm && validField
            }
        });

        if (validForm) {
            console.log(this.state.fields);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem resides in the on submit because the input is not retrieved correctly (I need a working code but it seems refs are not set correctly) while on event you pass the exact reference to the field coming directly from event. Check your refs and everything should work ok. As said from @SandipNirmal Formik has a great validation feature that you are substantially replicating.